# Why do my TextBoxes in different tabs of a TabControl lose their undo history?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, tabcontrol, undo

I have a `TabControl` with `TextBox` controls in the `ContentTemplate`. When I type some text in one tab and switch to another tab, the Undo history in the original tab is gone when I go back.

Another problem that comes up is any text that was selected is deselected and the caret moves to the beginning of the `TextBox`.

If I make a window with just hardcoded `TabItem` controls, the undo history is preserved. The issue has something to do with my binding or templates.

Here is my XAML for the main window

```
<Window x:Class="TabbedTextAreaTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Command="{Binding AddNewTab}">Add Tab</Button>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" Grid.Row="1">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Is there a way to preserve the undo/redo history and selected text when switching tabs **without** manually catching those commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a `TabControl` which gets its tabs via databinding on `ItemsSource`, WPF doesn't keep the visual tree for each item around as you switch. Thus, when you switch from tab 1 to tab 2, then back to tab 1, the controls on tab 1 are not actually the same control instances which you saw on tab 1 the first time.

There are a number of ways around to deal with this - `TabControl`s which have explicit `TabItem` instances do keep their visual trees when you switch tabs, so probably the easiest way to do it is to wrap your collection of tab items in something which makes `TabItem`s for them.

Unfortunately right now I can't find a link to an example of how to do this. There are references to articles elsewhere on SO, but they all seem to point to pages which no longer exist, and I don't have time to dig any deeper.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple. If you think the both operation you complain about are strictly UI operations: Undo: user editing on the **UI control**, selection: selection of the text on **UI control**.

When you swicth `Tab` to another and go back, what happens in WPF is that all controls are *rebinded* to there data (`ModelView` normally, or just `Model`) again, as if you was showing them for the first time. So they loose their UI appearance attributes.

To manage that correctly in `Tab` environment in `WPF` you need to manage `Undo/Redo` stack by your own.

Good luck.